# How to create universal link

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I have domain name and deployed the apple-app-site association file on sever as well.In web site I don't have much functionality , I will send a mail to all user that will have the dynamic link. How to create the dynamic link ??

Answer (score 1):

**There is no special way to create a Universal Link**. If you have registered the domain with you AASA file then any link with that domain that follows your AASA paths will open your app. You can just dynamically create urls with `yourdomain.com` as the domain and they should work accordingly. As Abhishek commented earlier, I'd highly recommend using [Branch](http://docs.branch.io) since you can easily bulk create links and the links are much stronger than stand alone Universal Links. They also have a web SDK that can generate links.